# GTK+3.0 compatible c++ wrapper version of gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm, gtk2, gtkmm3

I have to migrate a very large application developed in GTK 2.4 version to GTK 3.0. The current application uses Gtkmm version 2.4 in Ubuntu.

As GTKMM is the c++ wrapper of GTK+ , could someone tell me , whether and which version of Gtkmm will support GTK+3.0

Should I install and reference Gtkmm 3.0 or gtkmm 3.91 instead of gtkmm2.4 in my application? I cant find any documentation about which version of gtkmm should be used with gtk+3.0 application.

Comment: I would stick to gtkmm 3.22 as I suspect that 3.91 and friends are preparation for the gtkmm 4.0 version (which I wouldn't use until a few versions have come out).